# Only getting the last row in materialize select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, materialize

How do I change the value of a SELECT tag in MATERIALIZE CSS. I'm trying show the selected item that was stored from the database. I tried adding `.material_select()` at the end of the select but it only retrieves the LAST one in the row. How do I show every try ? Here's what I've tried so far.

```
  $(function() {

    <?php
    $q  =  $db->query("SELECT buildingID, buildingName,building_projectID, floorNumber FROM tblBuilding");
      while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
          $buildingID = $r['buildingID'];
          $buildingName = $r['buildingName'];
          $building_projectID = $r['building_projectID'];
          $floorNumber = $r['floorNumber'];
        $t = $db->query("select projectName from tblProject where projectID  = $building_projectID ");
        while($u = $t->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          $projectName = $u['projectName'];

    ?>
            $("#editModal<?php echo $buildingID ?>").click(function(){
              alert('<?php echo $projectName ?>');
              $("#editBuildingName").val("<?php echo  $r['buildingName'] ?>");
              $("#editBuildingProject").val("<?php   echo $projectName");              
              $("#editBuildingFloors").val("<?php  echo $floorNumber ?>");


            });
<?php }}?>   
});
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML as well? Did you try `$('select').material_select('destroy');` then  `$('select').material_select();` after updating your values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of:

> `$("#editBuildingProject").val("<?php   echo $projectName");`

use this:

> `$("#editBuildingProject").val("<?php echo $building_projectID ?>").material_select('update');`